# Convert Excel formula to C#

Tags: c#

I have the following formula in an Excel spreadsheet -

```
=100000*INT(RIGHT(A2,8)/65536)+MOD(RIGHT(A2,8),65536)
```

Example of results

```
660013103525 = 19961861

10014528196 = 22144740
```

I have been asked to add this conversion functionality in to a C# application. The spreadsheets purpose is to convert an RFID tag in to an unknown format number which an Access Control system recognizes.

All of my attempts at this in C# have been unsuccessful as I do not know what the forula is doing, or the final output format.

Comment: Do you understand what the formula does?  That's more important that figuring out the right syntax.

Comment: Show the code you are struggling with.

Comment: It converts an RFID tag to another unknown format number. I have literally been given the spreadsheet and asked to convert it to C#.

Comment: And you thought to copy/paste that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you your results. You can refine it a little more if you feel like it, but this should at least show you what is going on for each step.

```
string A2 = "660013103525";

int intA2, div, mod, output;
if (!int.TryParse(A2.Substring(A2.Length - 8, 8), out intA2)) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("A2");

div = intA2 / 65536;
mod = intA2 % 65536;
output = 100000 * div + mod;
MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat equivalent in C#.

Assuming you have numeric input stored in a string:

```
String input = "660013103525";
```

You can get the last 8 characters that correspond to the last 8 digits like this, and convert them to a number:

```
int val = int.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length-8, 8));
```

The final result follows from the formula:

```
int result = 100000 * (val/65536) + (val % 65536);
```

You can factor this into a method that takes a string and returns the integer value:

```
int ComputeValue(String input)
{
    // you should probably check input here

   int val = int.Parse(input.Substring(input.Length-8,8));
   return 100000 * (val/65536) + (val % 65536);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile (`Substring` needs a capital S) and doesn't give the right result. The output of that is 3525... Your arguments for `Substring` are inverted also.

Comment: You produce the wrong Substring: Substring(8, input.Length-8) should be Substring(input.Length - 8, 8)

Comment: Yep.. Typing the answer on my phone makes it a bit difficult. Fixed now

Answer (score -2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int factor = 65536;

        String cell = "660013103525";

        String str = cell.Substring(cell.Length - 8);

        long cellValue = Convert.ToInt64(str);

        long part1 = cellValue / factor * 100000;

        long part2 = cellValue % factor;

        long result = part1 + part2;

        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + cell);
        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + result);
    }
}
```

1. The above code takes input in the *cell* variable as a string.
2. Then, it creates an integer from it to do the *RIGHT(A2,8)* part of the formula.
3. Then, constructs the two parts of the formula using *cellValue* integer created in step 2.
4. Finally, it adds the two parts to get the final result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add some context to your answer? Code only answers are considered 'low quality' please have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Comment: Sorry for that! But I thought my code was self-explanatory and gives the output required by the original poster.

Comment: No problem, we have the review system to help new users, if you could edit your answer and at some context that would be great. And while your at it, the last closing } is outside of the code tag.